# Django manage.py syncdb error

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Hi I am very new to Django and I have been keep getting this error in my command prompt when typing in "manage.py syncdb"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\B3dog\Desktop\MyWebsite\mysite\manage.py", line 10, in <module>

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py3.4.egg\django\core\managemen
t\__init__.py", line 330, in execute_from_command_line`enter code here`
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py3.4.egg\django\core\managemen
t\__init__.py", line 304, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py3.4.egg\django\__init__.py",
line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.8-py3.4.egg\django\apps\registry.
py", line 89, in populate
    "duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, d
uplicates: admin
```

I am using python 3.4.1 and Django version 1.8 found by using django.get_version(). I know there are answers on stackoverflow about this, but I none of them that I have found are not up to date.

Edit: I forgot to include my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'pl=&jot_vf_(5ddtj6!pppl@ot^6@arj6(up76otxwqm3wj3)x'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mysite.db',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two entries of `django.contrib.admin` inside `INSTALLED_APPS`. Here's the fixed version:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

Comment: Why are you a genius. People like you who can see this stuff are gods.

Comment: @b3dog thanks, but it is really just following the info provided by the traceback and knowing a little about specifics of django settings. It is not that difficult. The more you work with Django, the more you would see and the more you would enjoy the framework :)

Comment: @Alvaro yeah, 1.8 is trunk currently.

Comment: @Alvaro What is so unstable about 1.8? I obviously don't know as a beginner.

Comment: @b3dog The Django team is "very good at maintaining their code stable". However it's always safer to stick to the current release, since it went through several stages of testing (both by the team and the users). I am using 1.6.5, waiting for the release of 1.7

Comment: @Alvaro Sorry one more question. What version of Python do you use seeing as you use Django 1.6.5?

Comment: This is argueable. If you are new to Django and you are exprimenting - it is ok to go with 3.x. If you are building a real-world app and you don't know your requirements yet - better be safe and stick to Python-2.7 - not all of the third-party batteries support 3.x, you will have more options with 2.x.